# Bing map Pushpin location based on address

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to create a pushpin for a location based on address [which may contain city,street etc]. I cannot use pincode since it is not standard across the countries.  Please anyone guide me how to go about it.

Thanks
Murali NM

Answer (score 0):

You have to call [REST based web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx) from Bing, indicating the whole address. Such service will return the GeoCoordinate (if it's found) which you will use in order to create the pushpin.

Cheers,

Comment: Is there any restriction on countries of usage of the service, because I got it worked for CountryRegion ="US","UK","DE" but unable to get for India [IN], I am getting not found exception. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can only add things to a map based on Latitude and Longitude (geo coordinate). there is no way to add things to the bing maps by adress.

you can do a call to a service from bing or google to retrieve the geo coordinate for a specific adress.

- [Google Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)
- [Bing Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I am getting exception as "'e.Result.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException".Below is mycode.           private void getGeoCoordinates(){     var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += OnOpenReadCompleted;
            string surl = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?CountryRegion=US&adminDistrict=WA&locality=Somewhere&postalCode=98001&addressLine=100 Main St.&key=AsIyeDMsvU4lhAVkckXTJE7mf9s1hEBSQTb2oFLaKdUcwUdUGLvJo0wzA5hjTO4q"; webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(surl, UriKind.Absolute));}

Comment: private void getGeoCoordinates(){     var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += OnOpenReadCompleted;
            string surl = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?CountryRegion=US&adminDistrict=WA&locality=Somewhere&postalCode=98001&addressLine=100 Main St.&key=AsIyeDMsvU4lhAVkckXTJE7mf9s1hEBSQTb2oFLaKdUcwUdUGLvJo0wzA5hjTO4q"; webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(surl, UriKind.Absolute));}

Comment: private void getGeoCoordinates()
{
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += OnOpenReadCompleted;
string surl = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?CountryRegion=US&adminDistrict=WA&locality=Somewhere&postalCode=98001&addressLine=100 Main St.&key=AsIyeDMsvU4lhAVkckXTJE7mf9s1hEBSQTb2oFLaKdUcwUdUGLvJo0wzA5hjTO4q"; webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(surl, UriKind.Absolute));
}
 void OnOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
var document = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
if (document.Root == null)
return;
}

Comment: I have pased the above code.  Please guide me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, Finally got it worked using "HttpWebRequest" and "HttpWebResponse". I could able to get lat and lang for US,UK but unable to get for India having country code "IN".  I want to know is there any restriction on country code to get geo information using REST services?